# VKsdk login causes app to hang

Tags: java, android, vk-sdk

I am trying to login to VK using VKsdk for android. When I press the button a login screen shows up, I press "allow" and login screen closes. But my app just hangs! And when i restart an App, I am still logged out. What am I doing wrong?

Here is code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()){
        VKSdk.login(MainActivity.this, VKScope.AUDIO);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [demo code](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/VKTestApplication/src/main/java/com/vk/vktestapp/LoginActivity.java).

Did you override `onActivityResult` in your *Activity* ? Something like :

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        VKCallback<VKAccessToken> callback = new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
                // User passed Authorization
                startTestActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                // User didn't pass Authorization
            }
        };

        if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, callback)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```